# Does FileUtils require an unavailable Ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building my first Rails application and want to include FileUtils in order to manage my Google sheets API (I got it to work in a standalone script).

However when I add FileUtils to my gemfile and use `bundle install` I get the following error:

> ERROR:  Error installing fileutils:
>          fileutils requires Ruby version >= 2.5.0dev.

And the most stable version of Ruby is 2.4.1.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not use the version in the [Standard Library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html)? I'm not sure why you would need to add this to your gem file.

You should be able to use it with any standard Ruby installation:

```
require 'fileutils'
```

Comment: So emphasizing that I am a total Ruby-newb. I built a script that had "require fileutils" - was using to figure out stuff before going through the trouble of building a whole rails app. Now I'm incorporating that script into a few functions in the Rails app. So I was trying to make sure fileutils was included in my bundler gemfile, not knowing really anything about Standard Library.

Answer (score 2):

> So what am I missing?

You are missing the fact that the gemification of the stdlib has only just now begun and is targeted at Ruby 2.5/3.0, so naturally that's what those Gems require.

Unless you are on Ruby 2.5, just use the stdlib version.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *that the gemification of the stlib is targeted at Ruby 2.5/3.0*? What exactly causes the requirement of Ruby version >= 2.5.0? I am just starting out with Ruby; an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If you realy need to specify the fileutils gem in your gemfile, use:

```
gem 'fileutils', '0.7'
```

as 0.7.1 requires a new Ruby according to
 https://rubygems.org/gems/fileutils/versions/0.7.1